# Error: Algorithm not found using grassprovider in PyQGIS standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

With QGIS 3.22 the GRASS algorithms got its own provider (`grassprovider.Grass7AlgorithmProvider`) and are no more part of `processing.algs`. Knowing this, in a standalone pyqgis-script I am trying to add the GRASS algs to the `processingRegistry` with `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(Grass7AlgorithmProvider())`.

If I am now trying to run a GRASS alg, e.g. `processing.run("grass7:v.dissolve", ...)` I get

```
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm grass7:v.dissolve not found
```

When I then list all the registered algs

```
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print("{}:{} --> {}".format(alg.provider().name(), alg.name(), alg.displayName()))
```

I get (after the entries of GDAL algs) a list of blank entries:

```
: -->
: -->
: -->
: -->
...
```

Obviously the GRASS algs are registered, but with no provider name and with no alg name resulting that I can't call the algs.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or I s it a bug?

Comment: This is a bug according to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45935